# UserControl LostFocus and UpdateSourceTrigger

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, .net-4.5

I have a UserControl that contains three buttons (ButtonA, ButtonB and ButtonC). These three buttons change the UserControl's Value dependency property.

When I try to use this control with UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus binding, it behaves incorrectly:

```
<custom:MyUserControl Value="{Binding SomeProp, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

When using LostFocus as UpdateSourceTrigger, the idea is to update the value of SomeProp only when control looses focus. The problem is that, when user clicks on ButtonA, then clicks on ButtonB, UserControl.LostFocus, and imediatelly after UserControl.GotFocus events are fired. This in turn updates SomeProp value.

So, how can I prevent this? When interacting with ButtonA, ButtonB and ButtonC, which are the children of MyUserControl, each time when switching from one button to another, UserControl.LostFocus is fired, and thats not what I want. I need for UserControl.LostFocus to be fired ONLY when control truly losses focus, and not when its children change focus.

Any ideas?

Comment: If i can remember correctly, i did not have luck using the "LostFocus" event in a stable and consistent manner. As the visual Tree does not seem to act as you would logically expect. It may come down to having to traverse the Visual Tree and see if it is a child or parent that is in focus. As if it is a parent then you would want the event to fire, while if it is a child (your buttons) you dont want to fire it. While it was a long time ago, this does remind me of the struggle you are having.

Comment: If you can figure out some way to do something when none of its children have focus, you can use `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` as the default for that binding, and then `System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(dependencyObject, dependencyProperty).UpdateSource();` in whatever event handler. Not a great solution, but maybe kludgable.